# MissingMethodException during Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, .net, activator, missingmethodexception

I have a Form class with this constructor:

```
public partial class PackageForm : Form
{
    Responder MfwuResp;

    public PackageForm()
    {
        MfwuResp = new Responder(new Responder.CancelHandler(StopMethod), true);
    }

    public void StopMethod(Responder responder)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancel Update");
    }
}
```

I also have a Responder class in a separate file

```
public class Responder 
{
    Type[] types;
    Object resp;

    public Responder(Responder.CancelHandler handler, bool isCancellable)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Update.Resources.AppUpdate.dll"));

        byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);

        Assembly assm = Assembly.Load(bytes);

        types = assm.GetExportedTypes();

        resp = Activator.CreateInstance(types[0], new object[] { handler, isCancellable });

    }

    public delegate void CancelHandler(UtilityResponder responder);
}
```

Whenever I create a new PackageForm in Main,
I get a `MissingMethodException`:

> Constructor on type 'AppUpdate.Responder' not found.

Any idea why does this happen? I suppose there's no problem on the syntax, since there is a constructor for CreateInstance that takes Type and params object[] as parameters.

Note: The Responder class is referenced from an external dll file, AppUpdate.dll.

Comment: Using types[0] is awfully risky, never do that.  You have two Responder classes, one whose code you posted in the snippet and another that you embedded as a resource.  That one has a different constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly are you completely sure `types` only contains `PackageForm`?

Anyway regardless, you are trying to create `PackageForm` with constructor parameters when it has only a default constructor (no parameters)

You probably only want to call this

```
resp = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]);
```